# Drop Down Menu hides behind images/js slideshow

Tags: html, menu, z-index, slideshow

I'm having a silly problem with a menu that hides behind a js slideshow on ASP.net. Basically I'd like that the menu could show all its options but I've tried a lot of solutions like z-index, position: relative and unfortunately nothing seems to work and I don't know why...

Do you have any idea why is that happening ?

**This is the code that I have in my html file**

```
 #imageSlideshowHolder{

        width: 915px;
        height: 255px;
        background-color:#000;
        border:3px solid #317082;
        position:relative;
            top: 0px;
            left: 0px;
            z-index: 1;
    }
.imageInGallery{        
    width:915px;
    height:255px;
    background-color:#000;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    position:absolute; 

 }

 #imageSlideshowHolder img{
        position:relative;
        top: 4px;
        left: 3px;
        height: 246px;
        width: 907px;
        right: 5px;
        z-index: 2;
    }
```

**My CSS for the slideshow**

```
body 
{
}
#imageSlideshowHolder{
width:907px;
height:246px;
background-color:#000;
border:3px solid #317082;
position:relative;

}
.imageInGallery{    
width:915px;
height:255px;
background-color:#000;

left:0px;
top:0px;
position:absolute;  
}
```

**And my CSS code for the menu**

```
div.hideSkiplink
{
background-color:#3a4f63;
width:100%;
height: 38px;
}

div.menu
{
padding: 4px 0px 4px 8px;
z-index: 1000;
}

div.menu ul
{
list-style: none;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
width: auto;
z-index: 1000;
}

div.menu ul li a, div.menu ul li a:visited
{
background-color: #465c71;
border: 1px #4e667d solid;
color: #dde4ec;
display: block;
line-height: 1.35em;
padding: 4px 20px;
text-decoration: none;
white-space: nowrap;
}

div.menu ul li a:hover
{
background-color: #bfcbd6;
color: #465c71;
text-decoration: none;
}

div.menu ul li a:active
{
background-color: #465c71;
color: #cfdbe6;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: can you please post your page link

Comment: Well, unfortunately I can't because is a project I'm working on but I have a capture of the menu if you want to see it http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/209/qqd4.jpg/
Inside the red box it should appear another option but is completely hidden by the slideshow and the holder @SonasishRoy